# Automatically build pod in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode7, cocoapods

For some reason I can't automatically build a pod in Xcode.

If I go to my project and click Build I always get `ld: library not found for -l<insert Pod name here>`.

I have to go to `Product > Scheme > <name of pod>` and then `Build` to build the Pod.

Once all my Pods are manually built then everything works. However, I'm sure there must be an automatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. What you are looking for is `Edit Scheme`. Click on your active scheme which is located in top left corner of Xcode, right near the Run and Stop buttons. Then go to `Edit Scheme...`

[image]

Next, go to `Build` tab and rearrange your targets so that your final target is at the bottom. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you SO much.  This comment is just to confirm this worked for anyone else having this issue. PS - not allowed to award bounty for 23hrs (will do so tomorrow)